# This is essential to be accepted or to/for being accepted by others

Tags: to-infinitive

can you please help me with this sentence. Which is correct? Or are they both? What is the difference?

> Many young people think that wearing trendy clothes is essential ...
>
> 1. to be accepted by others.
> 2. for/to being accepted by others.

I think the second one is correct, but maybe also number one is possible. I can't find an explanation why number 2 is better, it just sounds better.

Answer (score -1):

If you look the word essential up in a dictionary, you can see how it is used.

> **often** used followed by to + verb

When you use it in passive form, it should be used in " to be essential to be + past participle."

Comment: If you google ''essential to being accepted'' you will find many examples of the being + past participle form. So my question is: it this the correct one? Exapmples: "Successful participation" is essential to being accepted by peers...', ..'were considered essential to being accepted as part of the business discourse, ...'

Comment: I think the point is here that you can use infinitive form of a verb after the word essential such as "essential to do something". However, at the same time you can use "noun clause" after it . You can say " it is essential for /to  + noun clause". In this noun clause ,and you can change a verb  to a noun by adding ing, which is called nomalisation.

Comment: This might help http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/essential-for-or-essential-to

Comment: So you can say : "It is essential to archive a good result." or "it is essential to achieving a good result." However, "achieving" is not verb here. It is part of the noun phrase. ( I hope I am not wrong)

Comment: OK, thank you. so in my sentence both options are correct?

Comment: I am sorry I am not an authority on English grammar so I cannot say it is correct or not.